# cordova fs.root.getDirectory fails on samsung android phones (PATH_EXISTS_ERR)

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile, cordova-plugin-file

This Cordova code works on iOS and most Android devices, but fails on some Samsung devices:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem, gotFileError); 

function gotFileSystem(fs) 
{   
    fs.root.getDirectory(
        'my_folder',
        {create: true}, 
        function (entry) { 
            // Yay! Got the directory,
            // unless running certain Samsung Android devices,
            // in which case the "gotFileError" function will
            // run with the error FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR
        }, 
        gotFileError
    );

});
```

What's up with Samsung?
Or, more importantly, how can I make this work on all Samsung devices too?

Comment: Dont try to create a directory that already exists.

Comment: @greenapps - how would you check if the directory already exists?

Comment: Sorry. I dont use Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

Apparently in Android 6.0.0 and onwards it has been determined that apps must explicitly ask permission to write to the file system ([ref](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)) and all existing apps can just break.
I checked the version of Android for the devices I had that were failing and both were 6.0.1.

#### The fix

**1.** Install the "[cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)"
   `$ cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic` .

**2.** Add this logic in before calling fs.root.getDirectory()

```
function gotFileSystemButNowCheckForWritePermission(fs)
{
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission(
        function(status){
            switch(status){
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                    console.log("Permission granted");
                    gotFileSystemAndAccessPermission(fs);
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                    console.log("Permission denied");
                    alert('App needs access to the phones file storage in order to run');
                    gotFileSystemButNowCheckForWritePermission(fs);
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                    console.log("Permission permanently denied");
                    alert('Cannot run App without access to the phones file storage');
                    break;
            }
        }, 
        function(error){
            console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
        }, 
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );
}
```

---

*(special thanks to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779916/1290746 )*

---

#### Further info

All apps, even Facebook and Twitter, need to do this now.
In fact they are often adding an extra message before the Android system message for permission:

https://www.androidcentral.com/run-permissions-why-change-android-60-may-make-you-repeat-yourself

See also : http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/07/android-m-begins-locking-down-floating-apps-requires-users-to-grant-special-permission-to-draw-on-other-apps/

> "Android M may soon earn a reputation for an overabundance of
>   confirmation dialogs, at least that's how it will feel to anybody
>   setting up a new device. Fortunately, we need only grant each
>   permission to an app once, so things will never get as bad as Windows
>   Vista."

Tech info : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
More info : https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

According to this : https://medium.com/prodgasm/obtaining-app-permissions-the-right-way-and-humanizing-the-process-1c9e2d6d5818 : one could add some extra text to the prompts.